# How to make sure my documentation of types and functions appear in Ballerina central?

Tags: ballerina

I documented the public types and functions of my [Ballerina](http://ballerina.io) code using the documentation syntax:

```
documentation {
    Wordpress Client object
    E{{}}
    F{{wordpressApiConfig}} - Wordpress connector configurations
    F{{wordpressApiConnector}} - WordpressConnector Connector object
}

public type WordpressApiClient object {
    public WordpressApiConfiguration wordpressApiConfig = {};
    public WordpressApiConnector wordpressApiConnector = new;

    documentation {Wordpress connector endpoint initialization function
        P{{config}} - Wordpress connector configuration
    }
    public function init(WordpressApiConfiguration config);

    documentation {Return the Wordpress connector client
        R{{}} - Wordpress connector client
    }
    public function getCallerActions() returns WordpressApiConnector;

};
```

However, this documentation doesn't appear on [Ballerina Central](https://central.ballerina.io)'s package description once I push it. I checked some repositories which do show the documentation and observed they follow a different syntax which involved line comments and + signs.

Can you please explain what documentation style is the current standard and if I have to run a different command for document generation so it appears properly in the Central.

Comment: There has been a change in the documentation syntax. Please find it in the language spec here: https://ballerina.io/res/Ballerina-Language-Specification-WD-2018-07-12.pdf

Comment: You can now view the documentation in central. - https://central.ballerina.io/pasanw/wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation syntax you have used here is an old syntax. This was updated recently and now the Ballerina flavored markdown documentation syntax is used for documentations. More details can be found at https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/documentation.html.

So documentation in your examples should be changed as -

```
# Wordpress Client object
# + wordpressApiConfig - Wordpress connector configurations
# + wordpressApiConnector - WordpressConnector Connector object

public type WordpressApiClient object {
    public WordpressApiConfiguration wordpressApiConfig = {};
    public WordpressApiConnector wordpressApiConnector = new;

    # Wordpress connector endpoint initialization function
    # + config - Wordpress connector configuration
    public function init(WordpressApiConfiguration config);

    # Return the Wordpress connector client
    # + return - Wordpress connector client
    public function getCallerActions() returns WordpressApiConnector;

};
```

This change is not yet available in the Ballerina stable version, but will be available with v0.982.0 which will be released later this week. Also this change is available with the [nightly build](https://ballerina.io/downloads/). So you can use the nightly build until the stable version is released.